# What does this structure of the URL mean? http://www.example.com/?i=0

Tags: urls

I have been asked to switch between the existing front/home page of a website which has the URL

```
http://www.example.com
```

to a differnt page with the URL

```
http://www.example.com/?i=0
```

It's a very old website (twenty twelve theme), and I can't understand what this `?i=0` means, and how they built this specific page.

**To add clarity**

In the website `www.example.com` there is a page which has a URL structure that is different from all other pages and this is the URL: `www.example.com/?i=0`

The client wants that this page (`www.example.com/?i=0`) will be the home page and not an inner page, so I am trying to understand how to build it. Now it is not in the WordPress pages list, it's not a post or a category. I have also tried to disable all the plugins, but it didn't effect the page URL or its content, so I don't know where this page is coming from.

Comment: Is this WordPress?

Comment: yes it's WordPress

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have some url parameter loading from site, as reaction to some plugins, or file, or some changes, or behavior on site that may be loaded by some php code. In this scenario it can't be exactly seen where is it coming from, but it looks like starting some type of increment. 
But most important you can't just change the url site with added paramete ?i=0 that is not the way this functions, and you can't change your adress to something like this. 
If you need to transfer your site from domainexample1.com to domainexample2.com/?i=0 you shouldn't worry about this ?i=0 because if you are going to delete all content from domain2 and put there domain1 content it will not happened as this ?i=0 part is result of some functionality on this site.

Comment: No problem, I have seen, it doesn't make much sense to me why would your client even pay attention to this, because this is not anything related to design or something similar, so you should find out what is his reason for wanting this url? Please understand that you can't build homepage on url, because this extension is not a part of actual url, it just indicates that something is happening or communicating with database on this example.com url. I hope you understand and it helps you

Comment: thank you any direction where to look to find where this part of the url is coming from?

Comment: well can you send url so I can see?

Answer (score 0):

In very general sense this looks like an arbitrary GET query. WP uses these extensively in a raw form or (commonly) hidden under a layer of pretty permalinks.

However `i` specifically doesn't seem to be any query variable name WordPress recognizes natively. Most likely it is something custom to the site (or maybe some extension installed). You will have to track down in code what exactly accesses this value and for what reason.

Comment: thank you any direction where to look to find where this part of the url is coming from?

Comment: No remote idea. As per answer it's unlikely to be from WP core, so anywhere else... Search for accesses of `$_GET` global and such.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult for someone here to tell you where to look as it could be anywhere.
I suggest you download all your wordpress files on to your computer and then use a text editor to search those files for `$_GET['i']` and `$_REQUEST['i']` which will probably help you find where to start looking.